# java ee websocket chatroom try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5

Tags: java, websocket

> Error message : try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5

Full error message:

> \App\workspace_eclipse\EmpressFinance\src\main\java\com\empress\jpmc\chat\chatroom.java:[58,5]
>   error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5

code :

```
private String buildJsonData(String username, String message) {

        JsonObject jsonobject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("message",username+ ": "+message).build();
        StringWriter stringWritter = new StringWriter();
        try(JsonWriter jsonwritter = Json.createWriter(stringWritter)) 
        {
            jsonwritter.write(jsonobject);
        }

        return stringWritter.toString();
    }
```

full code of java:

```
package com.empress.jpmc.chat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set; 

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;


@ServerEndpoint("/chatroomServerEndpoint")
public class chatroom {
    static Set<Session> chatroomUser = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen(Session userSession)
    {
        chatroomUser.add(userSession);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose(Session userSession)
    {
        chatroomUser.remove(userSession);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException
    {
        String username = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");

        if (username==null)
        {
            userSession.getUserProperties().put("username", message);
            userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData("System","You are connected as" + message ));
        } 
        else
        {
            Iterator<Session> iterator = chatroomUser.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next().getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData(username, message));
        }

    }

    private String buildJsonData(String username, String message) {

        JsonObject jsonobject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("message",username+ ": "+message).build();
        StringWriter stringWritter = new StringWriter();
        try(JsonWriter jsonwritter = Json.createWriter(stringWritter)) 
        {
            jsonwritter.write(jsonobject);
        }

        return stringWritter.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the error "_try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5_". You are trying to compile this code with Java 5, you need Java >= 7. Set it in the Eclipse project settings.

Comment: but i cant change 1.5 becouse other part of code will be erroring :D

Comment: "_becouse other part of code will be erroring_" is hardly a helpful comment (not least the spelling). Please post the **full** details of your issues.

Comment: I solved this... In preferences of eclipse a JRE/JDK was unchecked ;/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Adding this snippet to your pom.xml will fix the issue.